# pandas - mask dataframe by column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Starting from this simple dataframe `df`:

```
col1,col2
1,3
2,1
3,8
```

I would like to apply a boolean `mask` in function of the name of the column. I know that it is easy for values:

```
mask = df <= 1

df = df[mask]
```

which returns:

mask:

```
    col1   col2
0   True  False
1  False   True
2  False  False
```

df:

```
   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1   NaN     1
2   NaN   NaN
```

as expected. Now I would like to obtain a boolean mask based on the column name, something like:

```
mask = df == df['col_1']
```

which should return:

mask

```
    col1   col2
0   True  False
1   True  False
2   True  False
```

EDIT:

This seems weird, but I need those kind of masks to later filtering by columns seaborn heatmaps.

Comment: Sorry but why show the cols that don't meet the criteria? You can filter by doing `df.filter(['col1'])` or `df[df.columns[df.columns == 'col1]]`

Comment: @EdChum thanks! Actually the `True` values belongs to the values corresponding to the column name that I would like to select.

Comment: Well you can just do `df.columns == 'col1'` which will return a boolean mask

Comment: @EdChum yes but it returns a mask only over the column names `[True False]`, not on the corresponding values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, situations where you would need to get a "mask" like that seem rare (and chances are, you not in one of them). Consequently, there is probably no nice "built-in" solution for them in Pandas.

None the less, you can achieve what you need, using a hack like the following, for example:

```
mask = (df == df) & (df.columns == 'col_1')
```

**Update:**. As noted in the comments, if your data frame contains nulls, the mask computed this way will always be `False` at the corresponding locations. If this is a problem, the safer option is:

```
mask = ((df == df) | df.isnull()) & (df.columns == 'col_1')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns a wrong mask, populated only with `False`

Comment: Obviously, you need to substitute the correct column name. I have no idea whether it should be `col1` or `col_1`, or anything else.

Comment: Note that `df == df` will be False where an element is null; depending on the situation this could be a problem, or not.

Comment: True. Updated the answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose your dataframe than compare it with the columns and then transpose back. A bit weird but working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
col1,col2
1,3
2,1
3,8
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
mask = (df.T == df['col1']).T

In [176]: df
Out[176]:
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     1
2     3     8


In [178]: mask
Out[178]:
   col1   col2
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False
```

**EDIT**

I found another answer for that, you could use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method:

```
In [41]: df.isin(df.col1)
Out[41]:
   col1   col2
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False
```

**EDIT2**

As @DSM show in the comment that these two cases not working correctly. So you should use @KT. method. But.. Let's play more with transpose:

```
df.col2 = df.col1

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     2
2     3     3

In [147]: df.isin(df.T[df.columns == 'col1'].T)
Out[147]:
   col1   col2
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False
```

Comment: `df.isin(df.col1)` works here only by coincidence-- try it with `df["col2"] = [3,2,8]`, for example.  Actually, come to think of it, your transpose method only works by coincidence too. :-/  Try it with `df["col2"] = df["col1"]`.

Comment: @DSM Yeah, you're right... Thank you, I'll try to find another way